# Как убрать курсор?

Tags: android

Вывожу данные списком, а сверху есть поиск - EditText и кнопка, для поиска элементов списка по названию.

Кликнув по текстовому полю появляется курсор и клавиатура, а при нажатии "отмены" на телефоне пропадает клавиатура, а курсор остается. Как сделать так, чтобы и он пропадал?

Comment: на событие "прятания клавиатуры" поставить операцию, забирающую фокус у едита.

Comment: @metalurgus, а можно на коде показать?    
Имею ввиду обработка события "прятания клавиатуры"

Comment: Нет такого события "прятания клавиатуры" у Activity или подходящего интерфейса только если свой велосипед делать или клаву!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Коротко и ясно: `editText.setCursorVisible(false);`

**UPD:** вот пример реализации такой вещи :)

```
//это тот самый интерфейс, который будет ниже   
public interface IOnKeyBoardHide
{
    public void disappeared(boolean b);
}

//пример реализации своего edittext в котором можно отследить, открыта или скрыт клавиатура
    public class CustomEditText extends AutoCompleteTextView
    {
        public CustomEditText(Context context)
        {
            super(context);

        }

        public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
        {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
        {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

        private OnClickListener onClickListener  = new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
               boolean b = getResources().getConfiguration().keyboardHidden == Configuration.KEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES;
                if(boardHide!=null)
                    boardHide.disappeared(b);

            }
        };

        private boolean hide = true;
        //интерфейс, который говорит о том, скрыта или показана клавиатура
         private IOnKeyBoardHide boardHide;
        public void setBoardHide(IOnKeyBoardHide boardHide)
        {
            //если не надо  отлавливать клик, то можно это бурать
            super.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

            this.boardHide = boardHide;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
            {
                boolean b = getResources().getConfiguration().keyboardHidden == Configuration.KEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO;
                if(boardHide!=null)
                    boardHide.disappeared(b);
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
            }

            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }

    //вот пример искользования
    CustomEditText myEditText = new CustomEditText(Context);
    myEditText.setBoardHide(new IOnKeyBoardHide()
        {
            @Override
            public void disappeared(boolean b)
            {
                if (b)
                {
                   Toast.makeText(context,"is hide",1).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"is show",1).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Макс, это само самой но ему нужно чтоб при исчезании клавиатуры это делалось следовательно надо отследить это событие и только потом вызывать setCursorVisible. 
Для этого разработчики из гугла советуют реализовать метод http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyPreIme(int, android.view.KeyEvent)
Кстати просто добавить этот метод в код активити не достаточно нужно создать свой custom view от EditText!

Comment: @dr0id, да, я ошибся, но поправился :)